# R merging, I've looked everywhere but am lost

Tags: r

I have multiple df: df, and df1 up through df11.

Df has a list of all states and counties from the years 2010:2020.

Df1 has a list of states and counties for the year 2010, and data I am interested in for that year.

Df2 has a list of states and counties for the year 2011, and data I am interested in for that year.

Thats how the formatting goes, all through df11, which represents state and county data for the year 2020.

I first joined df and df1 using left_join, which worked great. Data was filled in for states/counties for the year 2011. I called this new merged data "maindata".
`maindata <- left_join(df, df1)`

When I tried to merge maindata with the next df, df2 (data for the year 2011), merging with left_join did not work, as data for the year 2011 was not filled in the main df. I tried to utilize:
`maindata <- merge(maindata, df2, all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)`

While this worked in filled in data for the year 2011, it created duplicates for each year that had data... I don't want duplicates filled with "NA" in my maindata df...

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: In R parlance, it sounds like you want to both "bind" your data (some data for year 2010 in some rows, add it to some other data for year 2011 in other rows), and "merge" your data (add more variables that are linked by keys to cross-reference two tables). One adds rows, the other (typically) adds columns. Hope that helps you find more references to answer your question.

Comment: @Quinten I tried doing so, but there is a character limit. Let me do shortened versions.

Comment: You can use `head(dput(df), 10)`.

Comment: @Quinten dput(df)
``` A tibble: 10 × 5
   STATE COUNTY STNAME  CTYNAME         year
   <int>  <int> <chr>   <chr>          <int>
 1     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2010
 2     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2011
 3     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2012
 4     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2013
 5     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2014
 6     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2015
 7     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2016
 8     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2017
 9     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2018
10     1      1 Alabama Autauga County  2019
> ```

Comment: @Quinten I apologize for not being able to include it in an edit.. I was on a public network, so I am blocked from posting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have three years of data (df1,df2,df3) and another data frame with additional information per county:

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = 2010, county = letters[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(year = 2011, county = letters[1:6])
df3 <- data.frame(year = 2012, county = letters[1:7])
df <- data.frame(county = letters, other_info = LETTERS)
```

We could stack the annual info with `bind_rows` and then augment that data using `left_join`, which will look for the common variables (`county`) in this case and use those as a key between the original data and `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  left_join(df)
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "county"
   year county other_info
1  2010      a          A
2  2010      b          B
3  2010      c          C
4  2010      d          D
5  2010      e          E
6  2011      a          A
...
```